# Tooltip getting cutoff

Tags: css

I have a tooltip that becomes visible when hovering over a word. The tooltip is getting cut off and I can't exactly figure out why. In this example I'm hovering over a word that is blocked by the tooltip.

[image: AP]

Here is my CSS code for the tooltip

```
.graphtooltip {
   position: relative !important;
   display: inline-block !important;
   border-bottom: 1px dotted black !important;
   overflow: visible;
}

.graphtooltip .graphtooltiptext {
   cursor: pointer !important;
   visibility: hidden !important;
   background-color: white !important;
   border: 1px solid gray !important;
   color: #fff !important;
   text-align: center !important;
   padding: 5px 0 !important;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
   left: 50%;
   border-radius: 6px !important;
   position: absolute !important;
   z-index: 9999999 !important;
   width: 40vw;
   height: 27vw;
   overflow: visible;
}

.graphtooltip:hover .graphtooltiptext {
   visibility: visible !important;
}
```

I'm wondering what else I can try.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Like the HTML structure? Most likely, your tooltip is behind another div, so you need to use a `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` with a `z-index`

Comment: Can u please give us the HTML code or a link to a snippet so we can help